# upgrade CPLEX studio to academic version

Tags: cplex

I've downloaded CPLEX Studio 20.1 from https://www-03.ibm.com/isc/esd/dswdown/searchPartNumberResults.wss, and I use it with Python.

Unluckily, when running Python code, I get an error:

```
   CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded.
```

Even though I have academic account.

My question is: how can I upgrade my CPLEX studio to academic version?

If I run

```
python -m docplex.mp.check_list
```

In main Terminal I get:

```
* system is: Darwin 64bit
* Python version 3.8.8, located at: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python
* docplex is present, version is 2.18.200
* CPLEX library is present, version is 20.1.0.0, located at: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
* pandas is present, version is 1.2.4
* Your cplex version 20.1.0.0 is the latest available
> No problem found: you're all set!
```

However, if I run the same command in terminal in PyCharm (conda), I get:

```
* system is: Darwin 64bit
* Python version 3.8.10, located at: /Users/*username*/.conda/envs/bin/python
* docplex is present, version is 2.21.207
* CPLEX library is present, version is 20.1.0.0, located at: /Users/*username*/.conda/envs/lib/python3.8/site-packages
* pandas is present, version is 1.3.2
* Your cplex version 20.1.0.0 is the latest available
! Cplex promotional version, limited to 1000 variables, 1000 constraints

* diagnostics: 1
  -- Your local CPLEX edition is limited. Consider purchasing a full license.
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine which CPLEX runtime is used by DOcplex, run the `check_list` module
at command line (with docplex in Python path):

```
python -m docplex.mp.check_list
```

Comment: It is saying that it is just a Cplex promotional version, but I had an academic version before, but on windows

Comment: Can you post the output of the check_list module execution?

Comment: I've added the outcome as a part of the question

Answer (score 0):

you should change your path

see http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/getting_started.html

> docplex looks for the latest version of CPLEX Optimization Studio
> installed on your machine, by inspecting the CPLEX_STUDIO_DIRXXX
> variables, where XXX is the version of Cplex Optimization Studio

Answer (score 0):

This response is a bit late, but I encountered the same issue described in this post, and the following solution resolved it:

Please be aware that you are currently using the 'CPLEX promotional version, limited to 1000 variables and 1000 constraints,' which likely corresponds to the community version. This should be replaced with the Academic Initiative version.

To install the Academic Initiative version, follow the steps outlined in an article by Xavier Nodet, posted on July 09, 2020, available here: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/blogs/xavier-nodet1/2020/07/09/cplex-free-for-students. I will summarize the article's main points below, in case the link becomes non-functional:

Register for the IBM Academic Initiative program at https://www.ibm.com/academic/home.
Download the unrestricted CPLEX version by following these steps:

> "*Visit http://ibm.biz/CPLEXonAI, click on 'Software', and then find
> the 'ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio' card. There, you'll find a link
> to register. Once your registration is accepted, a download link for
> the AI version will become available.*"